# php session not working with class

Tags: php, session

Here, I am trying to achieve session data from class

Here is an example code

**Directories**

```
classes
  -- General.php
  -- DB.php
templates
  -- header.php
  -- footer.php
index.php
config.php
GetAPI.php
```

**config.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();

/* Header Set */
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");

/* Set Default Timezone */ 
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');

/* Set locale information */
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL');

/* Get Current URL */
$currentURL = (@$_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "https://" : "http://";
$actual_link = $currentURL.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'/';

/* Define Base url it will use in whole website, it treat as global variable */
define('BASE_URL',$actual_link);
/* CURL Configuration */

function getCurl($link){
    $curl_handle=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,$link);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest"));
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "/etc/pki/tls/cert.pem");
    $buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
    $buffer_decode = json_decode($buffer);
    curl_close($curl_handle);   
    return $buffer_decode;
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
require_once("templates/header.php");
require_once("templates/footer.php");
```

**GetAPI.php**

```
<?php
/* Auto Load all classes */
require 'classes/Autoload.php';

/* Get Title */
function getTitle() {
    $general = new General();
    return $general->getTitle();
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['func'])):
    echo json_encode(call_user_func($_REQUEST['func'], $_REQUEST));
endif;
```

**General.php**

```
<?php
Class General {

    private $db;

    public function __construct () {
        $db = new DB(); 
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function getTitle() {
        $_SESSION['data'] = "xyz";
        return $this->db->query("select * from general");
    }
}
```

**header.php**

```
<?php
include (__DIR__). "/../config.php";
$_SESSION['xxx'] = "x";
$d = getCurl(BASE_URL.'GetAPI.php?func=getTitle');
var_dump($d);
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Here when I'm trying to print `$_SESSION` than it only shows `$_SESSION['xxx']` it is not showing data of `$_SESSION['data']` which is in `General.php`.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I think the fact that you are calling GetAPI.php from a curl request is going to cause funny things with your sessions

Comment: general.php  is included in GetApi.php. But GetAPI is not included in your script. You run a new http request to get some info from some url. But you don't give any cookies to that request, as far as I can see, to link that new request to the current user's session

Comment: so how can I solve that means how can I set a cookie for it?

Comment: @Andy what is the funny thing about it?  what if I want to do ajax on class? it will need a mediator for it that's why I am using curl

Comment: This just looks like a bad way to do things. You generally don't have your own PHP script do an external request to another of your PHP scripts in the same request. Also allowing the user to specify a function on the querystring directly seems like a security risk

Comment: This Api approach is not directly a bad way. But if you do use it, make sure to keep in mind how it works: it is a new request and all information needed to execute this request should be sent along. It is especially useful if you want to build one way to serve information to both a webapplication and let's say a phone app. So making use of SESSION would make your api only useful for requests directly coming from the same document root. And so what would be its advantage over a simple include()?

Comment: @IvoP So there is a any other approach to achieve it? i want api for website and phone also

Comment: easiest would be to build your getApi script completly apart from the website. Then you are forced to think of some kind of authorisation mechanism, or some kind of recognizing of the visitor (the script on "some" website or the app on a phone)